# Improve PostgreSQL query performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, database-design

When running this query in my server it's very slow, and I can't understand why. Can anyone help me figure it out?
Query:

```
SELECT
    "t_dat"."t_year" AS "c0",
    "t_dat"."t_month" AS "c1",
    "t_dat"."t_week" AS "c2",
    "t_dat"."t_day" AS "c3",
    "t_purs"."p_id" AS "c4",
    sum("t_purs"."days") AS "m0",
    sum("t_purs"."timecreated") AS "m1"
FROM "t_dat", "t_purs"
WHERE "t_purs"."created" = "t_dat"."t_key"
  AND "t_dat"."t_year" = 2013
  AND "t_dat"."t_month" = 3
  AND "t_dat"."t_week" = 9
  AND "t_dat"."t_day" IN (1,2)
  AND "t_purs"."p_id" IN (
      '4','15','18','19','20','29',
      '31','35','46','56','72','78')
GROUP BY
    "t_dat"."t_year",
    "t_dat"."t_month",
    "t_dat"."t_week",
    "t_dat"."t_day",
    "t_purs"."p_id"
```

Explain Analyze:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=12252.04..12252.04 rows=1 width=28) (actualtime=10212.374..10212.384 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..12252.03 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=3016.006..10212.249 rows=14 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (t_dat.t_key = t_purs.created)
        ->  Seq Scan on t_dat  (cost=0.00..129.90 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.745..2.040 rows=48 loops=1)
              Filter: ((t_day = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[])) AND (t_year = 2013) AND (t_month = 3) AND (t_week = 9))
        ->  Seq Scan on t_purs  (cost=0.00..12087.49 rows=9900 width=16) (actual time=0.018..201.630 rows=14014 loops=48)
              Filter: (p_id = ANY ('{4,15,18,19,20,29,31,35,46,56,72,78}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 10212.470 ms
```

Comment: how many records are there in these tables? is the indexing done?

Comment: t_purs about 600K records, t_dat about 9K. Indexes are set in t_purs.id, t_dat.t_key

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: Also, it's entirely unnecessary to put your "column" and "table" names in quotation marks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is difficult to say what exactly you are missing, but if I were you, I would make sure that following index exists:

```
CREATE INDEX t_dat_id_date_idx
    ON t_dat (t_key, t_year, t_month, t_week, t_day);
```

For `t_purs`, create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX t_purs_created_p_id_idx
    ON t_purs (created, p_id);
```

Comment: Hey, I've did some changiing in the indexes and it's now speed as the light! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't underestimate power of compound indexes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a **single column**  in your table:

```
t_date date
```

instead of `(t_year, t_month, t_week, t_day)`. The data type `date` occupies 4 byte. That would shrink your table a bit, make the index smaller and faster and grouping a lot easier.

*Year*, *month*, *week* and *day* can easily and quickly be extracted from a date with [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). Your query could then look like this and would be faster:

```
SELECT extract (year  FROM t_date) AS c0
      ,extract (month FROM t_date) AS c1
      ,extract (week  FROM t_date) AS c2
      ,extract (day   FROM t_date) AS c3
      ,p.p_id                      AS c4
      ,sum(p.days)                 AS m0
      ,sum(p.timecreated)          AS m1
FROM   t_dat  d
JOIN   t_purs p ON p.created = d.t_key
WHERE  d.t_date IN ('2013-03-01'::date, '2013-03-02'::date)
AND    p.p_id IN (4,15,18,19,20,29,31,35,46,56,72,78)
GROUP  BY d.t_date, p.p_id;
```

More important for performance is the index, which would then simply be:

```
CREATE INDEX t_dat_date_idx ON t_dat (t_key, t_date);
```

Or, depending on data distribution:

```
CREATE INDEX t_dat_date_idx ON t_dat (t_date, t_key);
```

[The sequence of column matters.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493) You may even create both.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your query is having sequential scans on `t_purs` and `t_dat`. Creating the appropriate indexes will help you make this query faster and avoid sequential scans.

```
create index index_name on t_purs(created) where created is not null;
create index index_name on t_dat using btree(t_key, t_year, t_month, t_week, t_day)
```

Run *explain analyze* after running the above two queries. You'll see the plan time and execution time will be reduced.